# Proving that it's impossible to prove irrationality of all real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Suppose that we are given a real number $r\in \mathbb R$, then certainly it is either rational or irrational. Let $S\subset \mathbb R$ be a set of real numbers for which it is possible to prove that $s\in S$ is an irrational number. Now I claim the following:

**Claim:** $S$ is at most countable.

**Proof:** Let $P$ be the set of all proofs in this universe. It's clear that $P$ is at most countable. Let $P'\subset P$ be a set of proofs that are used to prove that $S$ consists of real numbers whose irrationality can be proved. By Cantor's theorem and hypothesis, it follows that card$(P')=$ card $(S)\lt$ card$(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)$ and this proves the claim.

In other words, it's impossible to prove irrationality of all irrational numbers.

Is the above idea correct? Please let me know if something is wrong in this. And if my claim is true then it is also possible in similar lines to show that Euler Mascheroni constant may never be proven to be transcendental as there are not enough proofs (at most countable). Thanks. 
I am sorry if this question sounds very silly or trivial.

Comment: There are only countably many real numbers which can be *defined* in any way. Since it is very hard to prove something about a real number you can't define, I guess it's easy to see the claim is true. ;)

Comment: It is possible to specify a set $S$, prove every element of $S$ is irrational, and prove $S$ is uncountable.  Of course $S$ will contain some elements $x$ that cannot be described, but that is different than saying $x$ cannot be proved irrational.

Comment: As far as we know today, the following could happen:  Euler's constant $\gamma$ is irrational, but there is no proof in ZFC that $\gamma$ is irrational.

Comment: "Let P be the set of all proofs in this universe. It's clear that P is at most countable."  Why is that clear?  If you mean all proofs that just happen to have been written that is *infinitely* fewer than all proofs that *could* be written.  And I take "provable" to mean it *could* be proven.  Not that it *has* been proven.  And I see no reason the number of proofs that *could* be proven must be countable.  At least no "clear" reason.

Comment: @fleablood: I felt uneasy while making that bold claim about countability of P but didn’t have a concrete reason to disregard any of the two possibilities for P. :)

Comment: @fleablood it is "clear" because the number of statements(true or false) in a countable language is countable(although we need to be very careful about what "countable" means here)

Comment: @Koro the reason that your proof doesn't work, is because "Let $P$ be the set of all proofs in this universe" is not something we can state(in FOL), so claiming that $P$ is countable is not something we can do(regardless if it is true or false)

Comment: @GEdgar: probably my description of S was not clear. S= set of all irrational numbers which can be proven to be irrational. That’s what I wanted to say. It probably sounds silly. Would you please suggest any improvement in defining S?Thanks.

Comment: @Koro I would suggest to you to read about the "Math Tea argument"(or, more specifically, to read about what is wrong with the "Math Tea argument"), I feel like this will interest you(and will most likely answer your question)

Comment: @ℋolo: I'll read about that. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Maybe it should be mentioned that @ℋolo 's comment is (I think) a reference to Joel David Hamkins' study of the math tea argument

Comment: @ℋolo: You are right. That has probably answered my question. So I can't (well) define $P$ and so it's not a set so whatever follows is not valid on it as that is valid on sets. Right?

Comment: @Koro I am not sure what you mean by "so whatever follows is not valid on it as that is valid on sets", but I think you got the idea, because you can't (well) define $P$ (from inside the universe), the rest of the proof is invalid

Comment: @ℋolo: Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This claim is fallacious.  Just replace the adjective “irrational” with “positive” and you would conclude that any set of reals that is provably positive must be countable.  If you phrase it just right you could make this a true statement, but it clearly defies most reasonable interpretations of “proving positivity of all (positive) real numbers”.

It is not necessary for every individual element of $S$ to have a distinct certificate of irrationality in order for the entire set to be provably irrational.  The same proof can cover all elements of $S$ without explicitly naming each and every one (which is clearly impossible).

For example, define $f: \mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to \mathbb R$ by $$f(A) := e + \sum_{k\in A} \frac1{2^{k!}}.$$  This is irrational — in fact, transcendental — for every value of $A\subseteq \mathbb N$, and there are uncountably many such values ($f$ is injective so the range of $f$ is indeed uncountable).

Comment: (+1) Nice clarifying example using positive real numbers!

Comment: +1 The very first sentence makes me realize that my proof is wrong because if it were correct it would be impossible to prove positivity of all real numbers. Although I don't understand why this is happening and I also think that f(A) is transcendental is a very bold claim (though I may be wrong here as currently I don't know much about proving a number transcendental).

Comment: "If you phrase it just right,...". Can you please clarify that? Thanks.

Comment: @Koro Oops, I made a significant typo, it’s supposed to be a faster growing sequence than factorial.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: That is fine Erick but I wouldn't claim transcendence of $f(A)$ as boldly as you have unless I have strong reason behind (which is completely a different question).  What if that sigma converges to something like $\gamma$ (Euler mascheroni constant)? My point is that this example is only obscuring the original question and is probably not required. I'm happy with your first paragraph though.

Comment: @Koro I wasn’t sure about your intent initially, so I was carving out an exception in case you were being knowingly facetious.  A true statement would be “Let $S$ be a set of real numbers such that each $s\in S$ has a proof of irrationality.  Then $S$ is countable.”

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric. Although your first paragraph answers my question to a good extent. It seems that the true statement suggested is also not correct though I am also trying to understand it based on suggestion of "Math tea argument" by Holo in the comments above.

Comment: @Koro I don’t find it particularly bold.  If one of the values of $f$ converges to $\gamma$ it would be the same as if $\gamma$ were rational: the difficulty doesn’t lie in proving that the particular value is rational/transcendental, but in proving that $\gamma$ is equal to that value.

Comment: @Koro see [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) for similar examples of transcendental numbers.